# Electron with Angular and Express with SQLite works, but not when built with ElectronForge

Tags: node.js, angular, express, electron

I have a electron app with Angular Frontend and Express Backend with a SQLite DB.
It's working when run with npm run start-electron.

```
"start-electron": "ng build && electron .",
"electron": "electron main.js",
```

The main.js:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
const path = require("path");
const url = require("url");
const { spawn } = require("child_process");
let win;

function createWindow() {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
    },
  });
  const expressProcess = spawn("node", ["./server/server.js"]);

  // Handle Express server output
  expressProcess.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
    console.log(`Express Server: ${data}`);
  });

  expressProcess.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
    console.error(`Express Server Error: ${data}`);
  });

  expressProcess.on("close", (code) => {
    console.log(`Express Server closed with code ${code}`);
  });
  // Load your Angular app
  win.loadURL(
    url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, "dist/statikgenerator/index.html"),
      protocol: "file:",
      slashes: true,
    })
  );

  win.webContents.openDevTools(); // Open DevTools (remove in production)

  win.on("closed", () => {
    win = null;
  });
}

app.on("ready", createWindow);

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on("activate", () => {
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

Im creating a child process in my main Electron Process which runs the express backend, that works and I am writing into the DB, but when building with forge it doesnt anymore, because the express server isn't running. Angular frontend works properly when built with forge.

**How would I properly set up a Express Backend inside my Electron app?**